# Fetch Single Record from Custom Module Table

Tags: model, module

I have a custom module with a custom DB. The DB consist of `customer_id` field and inserted `customer_id` into it.

How can I get a single record based on customer_id passed, whereby customer_id is the unique field value in my DB table.

For example:

```
Mage::getModel('module/model')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customerId));
```

The above code should give me a single record instead of giving a collection.

If I use below code:

```
Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customerId));
```

it gives me a record in array, and I do not want to use a loop to fetch data.

Is it possible to load data by using my custom DB field name, like

```
$custommoduleobj= Mage::getModel(‘yourmodulename/modelname’)->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
```

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: yes Possible...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mage::getModel('module/model')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customerId))->getFirstItem();
```

or this:

```
Mage::getModel('module/model')->load($customerId, 'customer_id');
```

Comment: Silly me..I knew it already, but didn't think about using it. Thanks.

Comment: Marius,can you tell me,are you consider customer_id' is customer_id as table primary key

Comment: @AmitBera In both the approaches above it's not important if `customer_id` id PK or not.

Comment: that means... if  i have field firstname in this table...then i can one row using  Mage::getModel('module/model')->load($customerfirstname, 'firstname');

Comment: Yes. But if the field is not unique there is no way to predict what row you get.

Comment: ok thanks you every much..... upvote for you.Can please check this answer.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389145/how-to-sum-column-value-using-group-by-collection-in-magentousing-magento-stand/25389403#comment39608376_25389403

Answer (score 1):

yes Possible...
add this function on Model/Yourmodel.php

```
 public function loadByCustomerId($customerID)
    {
        $this->_getResource()->loadByCustomerId($this, $customerID);
        return $this;
    }
```

And then goto...Yourmodel.php class resource class at /Model/Mysql4/Resource ->Yourmodel.php

```
  public function ByCustomerId(YourmoduleNamesPace_YourmOdules_Model_YourModuel $Object, $customerId)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
        $bind    = array('customer_id'  => $customerId);
        $select  = $adapter->select()
            ->from('yourtable' array('table_primary_key'))
            ->where('customer_id = :customer_id');


        $customerId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
        if ($customerId) {
            $this->load($Object, $customerId);
        } else {
            $customer->setData(array());
        }

        return $this;
    }
```