# Magento2 getting single row by field from repository object

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am building an ajax using webapi. and it instantiates a repository model.
How do I load a single row by a field?
I need to check if an email already exist in the table.

Comment: Loading an object from model or can say getting one row from table is same as it's in magento1 see this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33019/fetch-single-record-from-custom-module-table , the only difference is to load or initiate a model or collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load first item as follows from model.

```
$firstItem = $repositoryObject->create()->getCollection()->getFirstItem();
```

And if you want field name then as follows.

```
$firstItemField = $repositoryObject->create()->getCollection()->getFirstItem()->getXxx();
```